# wchar_t to UTF-8 and back string conversion in crossplatform styled c program

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, wchar-t

My program is written as C language crossplatform one (at least linux and windows are supported currently). It sends and receives some data over the network in the custom defined packages. Today is good time to enable Unicode characters in this data. I consider the most compact and universal format for this task is utf-8.

So I gets null-terminated wchar_t* string from the console input to be able to handle all characters supported by the system the program is run on. Then I need to convert wchar_t* to utf-8-coded char* to send the data over the network.
Then I receives an answer from the other side and need to complete the same convertion backward to wchar_t*.

Is there a simple way to do these conversions in crossplatform manner? Do I need to use some heavy library like ICU or the things are more easy?

Comment: Unfortunately, the size of `wchar_t` and encoding used can vary between platforms and affect how the conversion would be done... using a library may be easiest.

Comment: Nominally, in C11, you can use the facilities in the `<uchar.h>` header.  In practice, not all platforms provide support for it — Mac OS X 10.11.4 does not have the header, for example.  You're likely to do best with ICU.

Comment: Normally wchar_t is either UTF-16 (Windows) or UCS-4 (the rest of the world). Both are almost trivial to convert to UTF-8 and back. This is not 100% crossplatform but 99.95% maybe. ICU for this purpose is a huge overkill.